# $n$-recollements and perverse t-structures

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ct.category-theory, triangulated-categories

A [recent preprint](http://arxiv.org/abs/1506.08266) on arXiv brought my attention on the notion of [$n$-recollement](http://arxiv.org/abs/1410.3223) (def. 2) a generalization of the notion of [recollement](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/recollement) among three abelian or triangulated categories behaving like a "short exact sequence" of such objects.

> I am interested in knowing whether there is an analogue for n-recollements of the "perverse t-structure", the construction of perverse sheaves, and suchlike.

For example, if I am given a $n$-collement

[image]

like in Def. 2, then each of the $n$ recollements obtained taking triples of  consecutive layers of functors defines a $t$-structure on $\cal T$; are these structures related? Is there any way to compare them?

(I contacted the author of the paper via email; nevertheless I think it's good to have a feedback from the whole community).